# how to copy the selected row in datatable to another table in database mysql

Tags: php, jquery, html

i have data in products in database and it all display to my datatable in php file. and now i have the selected rows in datatable and i want all the selected rows transfer to another table in database like from products to sales_order_holder when clicking the submit button. is it possible? .

```
<table id="example" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="display">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Brand</th>
      <th>Model</th>
      <th>Item Name</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>id</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php do { ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo ++$i; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_products['pid']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_products['brand']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_products['model']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_products['item_name_']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_products['price']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_products['id']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } while ($row_products = mysql_fetch_assoc($products)); ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this,

```
INSERT INTO table2 (col1,col2...)
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE selected row's id
```

If more than 1 row is selected, try using `foreach` or use `INSERT BATCH` to insert and `WHERE IN` in select

Comment: can you attach it in my code? like it's completed. for me to know how to use foreach. like what you said. thankyou for your fast response.

Comment: How user can select the rows??

Comment: @MarkAvila you have  checkboxes??

Comment: by using this        oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
    
    oTable.fnSetColumnVis( 6, false );
    
  oTable.$('tr').click( function () {
  
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');

Comment: on click of a row, you selecting the row?

Comment: no i can't use the checkbox it's conflict to my other plugins. so i have to use toggleclass to select the row and it has a css to fill the row when its selected

Comment: but how will you post the selected values?? You want to do it at once?? or on each click you will do??

Comment: i want to post all the selected row on clicking a submit button.

Comment: then you have to tore the values in some hidden field(selected rows).

Comment: yeah i did it but it only for one row what if two rows are selected. the value of row will be merge to the hidden field.

Comment: While adding value to hidden field, use comma saperated values. or use a global array, push the value to array on select, remove on unselect.

Comment: yes i think that's what im looking for thankyou for helping me. i need to learn this (use comma saperated values. or use a global array, push the value to array on select,)

Comment: Welcome. Accept the answer if it was helpful:)

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO table2 (val1, val2)
SELECT val1,val2 FROM table1 WHERE tableRowId = someID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a check box beside each row in the displayed table.These checkboxes should contain the id of the product as value. Then pass on the values of these checkboxes using ajax to some php script which will run the query.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#submit").click(function() {
  var x=0;
   console.log("start");

    var selected = [];
    $("input:checkbox[id=product]:checked").each(function(){
    selected.push($(this).val());
    });
    if (typeof selected !== 'undefined' && selected.length > 0) {

      var target= $("#target").val() ;
      var data = {
        products : selected.toString(),

    }



    $.ajax({
     url:"/dispatch",
     type: "POST",
     data:JSON.stringify(data),
     dataType: "json",
     contentType: "application/json",
     success: function(data)
     {           
            console.log("end");

     }
});

      }

});
});
```

Comment: thankyou for your response sir. but what if i dont have checkbox. i use toggleclass to get the row selected. it's onclick function.

Comment: Use toggleclass to get reference of the selected row, then get the id of that product from it and follow the same approach. I have never used it though, generally people use checkboxes. you can try